# Make target-specific assignment order

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider this Makefile with GNU Make (replace the spaces before `@echo` with a tab):

```
BAR := outside

foo:
    @echo $(FOO)

foo: BAR := inside
foo: FOO := $(BAR)

.PHONY: foo
```

The output is `inside`. If I swap the order of the two target-specific assignments, I get `outside`. This leads me to believe that target-specific variables are assigned in the order they are written.

**Is this actually documented? In other words, can I rely on it?** The behaviour makes sense, but I can't find any mention of it in the docs.

The closest thing I can find is:

> As with automatic variables, these values are only available within the context of a target’s recipe (and in other target-specific assignments). [1](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific)

Which acknowledges target-specific variables can be used in target-specific assignments, but doesn't say if the assignment order is handled like normal assignments.

The code posted is just a minimal example, actual code is ~800 lines split over multiple files, based on a metaprogrammed template system I wrote to dinamically generate *lots* of targets for various devices (it's a bare-metal SDK) in different build configurations. An example where this situation comes up is adding a linker map to `LDFLAGS` for debug targets, with the map path depending on a device-flavor tuple that is a target-specific variable for the linking phase. Right now I work around it using my template system, but being able to rely on the assignment order of target-specific variables would make some things less verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual doesn't explicitly guarantee this behaviour, but it's self-evident when you consider that target-specific variables only determine the scope of a variable name, not how and when it is set, and they otherwise act like regular variables.

I.e. there's no difference between this

```
foo: BAR := inside
foo: FOO := $(BAR)
```

and this

```
BAR := inside
FOO := $(BAR)
```

with the exception that the first example will first look for a definition of `BAR` in the scope of `foo` before moving up the chain, and the resulting definition will only be available within the scope of `foo`.

Comment: "Target-specific variables only determine the scope": much clearer now. Thank you.

Comment: Also, after reading the docs for the 10th time, I found [something](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) I had missed: "All variables that appear within the variable-assignment are evaluated within the context of the target: thus, any previously-defined target-specific variable values will be in effect".

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no surprise here - both assignments are immediate so order is everything just like for global variables